# Question closed automatically; how to improve?

Tags: discussion

I asked a simple [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1375119/facebook-is-terminating-my-internet-connection-on-pc) (only visible to 10K+ rep users) about Facebook terminating my Internet connection, provided all the information I had available.

What am I doing wrong? How to reopen and improve it?

Comment: Can't read the question but shouldn't you be contacting facebook support about this? Also, didn't know you could get internet from facebook. Also, gross.

Comment: Your question was closed and then 13 days later it was deleted.  It was closed because it wasn’t within scope here at SuperUser.  *The question might have not been closed in the first place if you originally submitted the final revision instead of the first question that absolutely deserved to be deleted.**. However, even with the final revision, you have not provided enough information to identify the cause of the problem you described

Comment: have not provided enough information? did you see the post?

Comment: @user648026 - Of course I did. I wouldn’t have submitted a comment if I didn’t

Comment: @Ramhound so how can you say "you have not provided enough information to identify the cause of the problem " the post is full of details and debug details

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for trying to improve your question. We want to help you with that.

As currently written, your question does not include enough information for anyone to provide a definitive answer. Therefore the appropriate way to improve your answer is to provide enough information.

You *were* doing that by editing your question in response to comments. However you stopped. For example, the last comment on your question is one I posted providing specific steps for you to take, but you did not edit your post with any of the requested information:

[image]

Until you can isolate your problem with enough detail, it will not be answerable.

---

Additional, I invite you to rethink your assertion that "Facebook is terminating your Internet connection." Consider the implications for your problem if you are correct:

1. Facebook is terminating your connection.
2. You don't control Facebook.
3. Therefore you can't control what's terminating your connection.

Clearly this assumption is unhelpful as it makes pursuing a solution pointless.

It would be better to focus on describing the symptoms you are experiencing and the results of the steps you've taken to try to solve the problem on your own. Let those posting answers use that information to follow the clues in order to make their determination about the cause and appropriate solution.

Answer (score -1):

The link you provided doesn't redirects to any relevant content (it's basically a page not found page) as far as your question goes: Facebook can not terminate your internet connection provided Facebook is not your ISP (Internet service provider). The most it can do is block your IP from accessing facebook.com or any other domains it owns. Just to bring a technical edge in this matter for better understanding, i'd explain how it works. when you open any link (say stackoverflow)your browser asks the ISP for providing the relevant page (a lot of things here like DNS etc but I would keep it short) and then ISP fetches you the page. So there is no way an entity other than the ISP can block your internet. Like I said earlier Facebook can always deny providing the services to your IP by blocking the requests (through firewall) but that won't prohibit you using other websites on the internet. If the later is the case(you are unable to open Facebook only) then try to use VPN services. On android I would suggest you to go for Turbo VPN / for IOS you can use TUNNELBACK. please let me know if I could help you further :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User and Super User Meta.  Good information here, but the wrong place to post it.  The main site is for technical questions about computers.  The Meta site (here) is for questions about using the site.  user648026's question here isn't the original question about Facebook terminating the connection.  This one is about how that question could be improved to make it answerable and in-scope on the main site.

Comment: BTW, this answer explains what the cause isn't, but doesn't provide a definitive solution to the problem.  There wasn't enough information provided in the original question for that, which is why it got closed.

Comment: Oh I am new here... pardon me and thanks for letting me know the work culture here. Would keep that in my mind next time I answer something here :)

Comment: @AnonymousDeveloper - If you cant see deleted answers, you can always leave it to those community members, who can see deleted answers

Comment: @Ramhound that's another piece of information I was unaware about. well thanks for the info. I learnt several new things today. BTW it's my second day here so my apologies if me being a noob disturbs anyone here :)